# Silent Installation of MySQL (version 5.7) on Windows with Batch Files

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, cmd

i'm trying to create a setup process for my C# application that use MySQL Database local (not online, every PC that will install my app, will get a clean Database to use). Searching around google i found that i need to make a "Silent" install of MySQL required components which are:

- MySQL Server 5.7
- MySQL Connector/Net

So I've done the following steps:

1) Downloading **mysql-installer-community-5.7.11.0.msi** from MySQL Home page

2) Made a Batch file "Setup.bat" that will create a Folder C:\MySQL and Copy there the Installer.msi and another batch file "Installer.bat".

3) After copying start Installer.bat with the command

```
Call C:\MySQL\Installer.bat
```

4) What Installer.bat will do:

```
@echo off

echo.
set password=admin
set installer="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\MySQLInstallerConsole.exe"
set version=5.7.11
echo -----------------------
echo Details
echo -----------------------
echo Server User: root
echo.
echo Server Password: %password%
echo.
echo Configuration Folder: %installer%
echo.
echo Version: %version%
echo -----------------------
echo Start Installation... (si prega di attendere alcuni minuti)
echo.

msiexec /i "%~dp0\mysql-installer-community-%version%.0.msi" /qb

%installer% community install server;%version%;X64:*:port=3307;openfirewall=true;passwd=%password% -silent

pause
```

- Installing the .msi file inside the folder,
- Download and Install the MySQL server 5.7

and from here start my problem, the Download and Installation of MySQL server 5.7 go well, but once it need to configure with my parameters it start to initilazie the server with several steps:

- Stopping Server [If Necessary]
- Writing Configuration file
- Updating Firewall

... and so on till i get this one

- Starting Server

Once there it will never complete, so I checked Windows Event Viewer and i found that two errors occur once the " Starting Server " step begin:

```
Error1 Failed to create datadir C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data

Then

Error2 Aborting
```

If i try to install those components manually with the GUI installer i don't get any error and everything works good, but i need to make them install and configure automatically, can someone help me please? (Sorry about my english)

Comment: "and from here start my problem" ... is this where you don't know hoo to continue or do you get any errors? I see the error message from your Event Log - but I cannot see where you start the server in your batch file.

Comment: @Gerfried
'%installer% community install server;%version%;X64:*:port=3307;openfirewall=true;passwd=%password% -silent'

with this command it start an installation and right after configure it with the parameters  port=3307;openfirewall=true;passwd=%password% and doing that " Starting Server " thing, all with that command

Is it the same when you launch the Msi installer manually and choose wich product to install, then configure the parameters of your server and once u press Execute button it will start the steps with " Starting Server " but there it will accomplish all tasks with no errors

Comment: Have you reviewed the page - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-installer-msi-quiet.html it does seem to be very comprehensive and appears to cover what is needed?

Comment: @leptonator Yes i followed the Mysql Manual for 5.6 but with no results, your link is for v 5.1 so much older

Comment: The point is with MSIEXEC and the implementation should the same if not very similar.  I did not see anything on Itninja.com as they have many methods there of how to silently install packages.  Have you seen the following?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx  I know there are other pages that handle install packages, but was way back when I was doing login scripting.  :)

Comment: Maybe silly - but have you tried to run your batch file with "run as administrator"?

Comment: @Leptonator the Msiexec works fine it's something wrong with the configuration of MySQL server. The msi just install the installer program for mysql packages, then the second line download the "MySQL server 5.7 " Package using a component stored on C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\MySQLInstallerConsole.exe
The installation of Mysql Server go Well but once it start to configure my server, it fails on create the "data" folder but i can't understand why it's happening...

Comment: @Gerfried yes they run as administrator